# How can I detect when a pdf file is not available via a link

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am developing a website with an archive of (hundreds) of old 'magazines' existing as pdf files. I can link to them with a normal 'a' tag but there are missing files, which are being slowly/gradually replaced as available. What I want to do is to have page links to all the files but automatically disable all links where the file is missing (maybe even with an explanatory popup). I could do this by hand of course but I'm looking for a coding approach (maybe js ajax?) which handles all page links. I have tried this with jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(href);
        $.get(href)
            .done(function () {
                console.log('File present');
            }).fail(function () {
                console.log('File missing');
            });
    });
```

I realize that 'preventDefault' stops the link working normally anyway but this is testing. However I get 'File present' even when the file is missing. Is this because pdf files respond differently and is there a perhaps simpler approach altogether?

Comment: I just tested a few things out and the problem that you are having could simply be the website where the PDF was hosted isn't returning a 404 message but instead a 200. Because when I run your code on URLs that I know don't exist on jsfiddle I get the file missing message.

Comment: Thanks for that. You are quite right. My controller method was setting the header as a pdf and although readfile() obviously didn't work, it still came up in the browser as a faulty but existing file. I've now added a flashdata message if the path doesn't exist and that seems to work OK.